# userChrome.css to reduce rounding of tabs on Firefox Australis interface

Tags: firefox, themes, css

Firefox's Australis interface (curse it) has brought heavily rounded tabs. (amongst so many other indecencies)

I could undo this by installing the extension Classic Theme Restorer, or a different theme, but I'd prefer to stop installing more and more layers of bloat. As more, Classic Theme Restorer will be killed by the end of XUL addons support…

So, I'm looking for the simplest possible set of rules to add to `chrome/userChrome.css` for reducing this tab rounding.

The rulesets I found on the internet are very large, and look like "blindly try rules and stack them until it looks fine". I tried to do it myself, but I'm getting many glitches e.g. when hovering with the mouse.

Comment: You'd probably want to start by examining the source code for Classic Theme Restorer, or browsing existing styles on userstyles.org.

Comment: As an alternative, the light themes introduced in [Firefox 53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_53) are easier to tweak and a better starting point for my needs. Also, an even better alternative is probably to switch to [Pale Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Moon_(web_browser))…